# VirtualBox - auto escape mouse

Tags: virtualbox, mouse

At the moment, if I want to use my mouse on my Host computer whilst I'm in VirtualBox, I have to press the left Cmd key on the Mac.

Is there a way to get the mouse to escape automatically?

I'm pretty sure VMWare automatically switches control of the mouse from Guest to Host when you reach the side of the Guest screen. And vice versa. But I can't seem to replicate this with VirtualBox.

Comment: Have you installed Virtualbox Guest Additions inside your guest OS? This should allow you to move your mouse from the guest OS screen to your host screen seamlessly.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** There's a way as [n8te](https://superuser.com/users/627136/n8te) suggested below in [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1142927/virtualbox-auto-escape-mouse/1142929#comment1641681_1142929) and as documented [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#idm1721),

---

Also, using these to these will get your mouse out of virtual box

- Open Launchpad <kbd>F4</kbd> (or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> is you
  use functional keys normally)
- Open Mission Control <kbd>F3</kbd> (or
  <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> is you use functional keys normally)

Or if you use trackpad use gestures:

- Perform Desktop Switching
- Open Launchpad
- Open Mission Control
- App Exposé

[image: Trackpad]

Comment: "The Guest Additions offer the following features:
Mouse pointer integration.
    To overcome the limitations for mouse support ..... this provides you with seamless mouse support. You will only have one mouse pointer and pressing the Host key is no longer required to "free" the mouse from being captured by the guest OS. To make this work, a special mouse driver is installed in the guest that communicates with the "real" mouse driver on your host and moves the guest mouse pointer accordingly."  [vbox documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html)

Comment: @n8te That's great! Updated my answer.

Comment: All good. Gives OP two options to accomplish his goal now.